# UITableViewCell has UITextField, cell can be removed but crashes when it is first responder

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder

I have a custom UITableViewCell, which has a text field in it, the cells can be removed, then I got a problem when the table is in editing mode and the cell also got first responder for the text field, in this case it just crashes say that I cannot delete a cell which does not resign first responder.

I tried to resignFirstResponder for the text field, when the cell is removed, but since the deletion happens immediately and the resignFirstResponder has an animation, so it still does not work.

Does anyone have similar issue and happen to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `UITableViewCell` acts as delegate for your `UITextField`. If so, then just try to set `UITextField` delegate to `nil` before deleting the cell.